# ERROR in Error: NgModule is not an NgModule

Tags: typescript, angular-cli

It was working very fine, suddenly it started giving me this below exception while running ng serve. I did not do any recent upgrade or dependency adding things also.

Can someone help me what should be done to resolve ?

```
ERROR in Error: NgModule is not an NgModule
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (E:\Going-on\czc-admin-startupui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:140:15)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (E:\Going-on\czc-admin-startupui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
    at E:\Going-on\czc-admin-startupui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:129:27
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (E:\Going-on\czc-admin-startupui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:128:10)
    at includeLazyRouteAndSubRoutes (E:\Going-on\czc-admin-startupui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:66:25)
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at includeLazyRouteAndSubRoutes (E:\Going-on\czc-admin-startupui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:67:26)
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (E:\Going-on\czc-admin-startupui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:54:36)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (E:\Going-on\czc-admin-startupui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (E:\Going-on\czc-admin-startupui\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:207:44)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (E:\Going-on\czc-admin-startupui\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:443:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "sb-admin-angular4-bootstrap4",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --ec=true",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.25",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^9.3.0",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^1.2.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
    "ng-block-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.15",
    "ng-spin-kit": "^5.1.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

I uninstalled, installed and tried again, but no luck.  Tried with latest typescript versions, but getting some other exceptions, so reverted back those changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a very silly mistake, added NgModule also to the imports. I just removed it then this issue resolved.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AddBannerComponent } from './add-banner/add-banner.component';
import { BannerComponent } from './banner.component';
import { BannerRoutingModule } from './banner-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports:[NgModule,BannerRoutingModule],
  declarations:[AddBannerComponent,BannerComponent],
  providers:[]
})
export class BannerModule{

}
```

Resolved code: (Removed NgModule from the imports)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { AddBannerComponent } from './add-banner/add-banner.component';
    import { BannerComponent } from './banner.component';
    import { BannerRoutingModule } from './banner-routing.module';

    @NgModule({
      imports:[BannerRoutingModule],
      declarations:[AddBannerComponent,BannerComponent],
      providers:[]
    })
    export class BannerModule{

    }
```